# Modify CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to modify `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` to 'trick' CMake into thinking the top level `CMakeLists.txt` file is somewhere else?

I have the following directory structure:

```
\src            <--- not a repository
    \cmake      <--- repository
    \common     <--- repository
    \project1   <--- repository
    ...
    CMakeLists.txt   <--- would like to locate this inside the cmake repository
```

The problem with the above structure is that the top-level CMakeLists.txt lives outside any repository, so it is not possible to check in changes.

Is it possible to locate that file inside the `cmake` directory (which contains nothing else), and still run CMake 'as if' the file was located in the `src` directory?

*NOTE*

1. I've been gifted this split-repository layout by a client, no need to tell me it causes problems.
2. Copying the CMakeLists.txt file in and out of the `src` directory will of course work, but I'm looking for a solution that runs less risk of forgetting to copy the file back into a source-controlled directory.
3. I've played around with modifying the CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR variable from within the script, but this doesn't actually change the working directory.

Answer (score 11):

Modifying `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is not possible and should not be attempted.

The problem is this: If a project is supposed to be build as part of an enclosing CMake project (that is, it's being included via `add_subdirectory`), it must not rely on the assumption that it is being built as a top-level project anywhere. In particular, variables like [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) and [`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_BINARY_DIR) must be used with great care, as they always refer to the top-level CMake project. The corresponding [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR) and [`PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aPROJECT_BINARY_DIR) should be used instead.

From what you have described, you might be in one of two situations: Either the project in question was never meant to be built as part of another enclosing CMake project, in which case you probably should not attempt to do so. Take a look at [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject) for an alternative for building the project stand-alone as part of your enclosing project's build process.

If, on the other hand, the project in question was supposed to support this build setup, it simply has a bug in the CMake script and you should strive to get the `CMAKE_*_DIR` variables replaced by their `PROJECT_*_DIR` equivalents.