# Can a CMake project in Visual Studio reference source files in a parent folder?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cmake, project

I newbye with Visual Studio / CMake solution that I would like to use to compile on remote Linux OS from a Windows platform.

I have a complex source structure that use C++ file through different folders.

```
/trunk
/trunk/projects/project1/
/trunk/projects/project2/
/trunk/src1/
/trunk/src2/
/trunk/src.../
/trunk/external-libs/
```

[Source structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orb5H.jpg)

My cmake projects are located at /trunk/projects/. The first project uses *some files* from src1 and src2 and external-libs, the second project uses *different files* from src1 and src2 and external-libs...

- Is it possible to target files that are in a parent folder of the cmake project? It seems that source can only be on the cmake project folder/subfolder. Please confirm!
- If it is possible how such reference to can be done to these files in the CMakeLists.txt and how Visual Studio will synchronize these files on the linux remote folder?
- One pratical way to do this would be to specify the source root folder (/trunk) through the CMakeSettings.json which is created by Visual Studio. Unfortunately this setting does not seems to exists. Am I wrong? It would be very useful so the solution would operate as if it is located at /trunk and we can then operate through specific CMakeList dedicated to project1, project2.

Actually it seems that the only way to operate is to copy the required source from src1, src2 to the cmake-project1 and cmake-project2, which is not particularly convenient for the structure lisibility.

But I may be completely wrong about the right approach for this kind of problem!

Thanks for your suggestion!

**Update**.
Try to play with CMAKE_SRC_DIR as suggest by @botje
But the source cannot be found by CMake because there is no copy to the remote system done by Visual Studio from the Windows folders.

[Some tries to relocate source dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IVPH.jpg)

```
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] CMake Error at D:\trunk\projects\project1\CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
1> [CMake]   Cannot find source file:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     ./src1/project1.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `CMAKE_SRC_DIR` seems to work for me:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_SRC_DIR=/path/to/trunk /path/to/trunk/projects/project1
```

Source file references are by default relative to the CMakeLists.txt; if this sits within the tree defined by `CMAKE_SRC_DIR` it *may* just work with visual studio.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be a linux only solution. Visual Studio does not take care of this new root. If I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214349/modify-cmake-source-dir, it is said that's not a good idea to modify CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR, and this is better to play with PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR, but I am not sure at all.
I update the request with some screen capture to help understand